# When i execute the following program in turbo c++ its not letting me enter the book title and author's name instead it shows 'abnormal termination'

Tags: c, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct books {
    int id;
    char title;
    char author;
    int year;
    long isbn;
};

int main() {
    struct books b;
    clrscr();
    printf("\n Enter BOOK ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&b.id);
    printf("\n Enter BOOK TITLE: ");
    scanf("%s",&b.title);
    printf("\n Name of AUTHOR: ");
    scanf("%s",&b.author);
    printf("\n Enter YEAR: ");
    scanf("%d",&b.year);
    printf("\n Enter ISBN: ");
    scanf("%d",&b.isbn);
    printf("\n BOOK ID: %d \n ",b.id);
    printf("\n TITLE: %s \n ",b.title);
    printf("\n AUTHOR: %s \n ",b.author);
    printf("\n YEAR: %d \n ",b.year);
    printf("\n ISBN: %d \n ",b.isbn);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when i execute this I get to enter the values for id,year and isbn but for title,and author when i enter the names it shows 'abnormal termination' can someone please tell me what did i do wrong?

Comment: you allocate a single `char` for the `title` and `author` fields. Also you are using incorrect format specifier for `long`.

Comment: Are you being forced to use Turbo C++? If not, please, let it go. It's served us well, but it's extremely out of date.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

you are entering title which is a `std::string` but you are using `char` which can be causing an error. Also you are using `%d` for long which is wrong as you should be using `%ld` for that.

Not only that sometimes it is not your code that produces the error but Turbo C++ that causes it. So try to relaunch Turbo C++ and if possible run the same code on another IDE to check if the code is actually wrong.